# Date format - Should I use st, nd, th?

Tags: dates

Which one is better to use?
"Today is June 30, 2017" or 
"Today is June 30th, 2017"

What about in sentences without a year?
"... something will happen on June 13" or ".
.. something will happen on June 13th"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, we leave off those appendages when it comes to written dates. However, there are some times where they will creep up.

When these annotations are used, the date format typically changes, and the word “of” is used. For example, you might see one of these:

> - The sale will happen on June 13
> - The sale will happen on the 13th of June

but I think the first one is quite a bit more common than the second.

There’s nothing wrong with `June 13th` per se, but I don’t think you’re likely to find that format in too many places.

That said, you might find that kind of numeration used when the month is omitted:

> - The 13th falls on a Friday this month.

Comment: **13th of June** is slightly more formal than **June 13**. "**June 13th**" is rather strange don't you think?

Comment: @SovereignSun - If I thought it was strange, I would have said it was strange. Have you Googled a date in that format and seen how many hits you'll get?

Comment: @J.R. Out of curiosity - when you read your first sample aloud ( _"The sale will happen on June 13"_ ) do you pronounce the _-th_?  I do, but I also almost always write it, except at my workplace where the awkward convention is to write _"The sale will happen on 13 June."_

Comment: @J.R. Yes, I did. It's still strange to me because I'm not English.

Comment: @SovereignSun - If you're here as a learner, then you've learned something new :-)

Comment: @J.R. definitely, the more I answer and ask the more Englush I become.

Comment: @Adam - Sometimes I do pronounce the *-th*, and sometimes I don't. I elaborated on that very topic over on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81539/saying-dates-in-english/81549#81549) a few years ago.